# Unity Android I have written .csv into application.persistantdatapath and i cannot upload it from android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have built a game that receives input from player and writes it as .csv in application persistent data path, and uploads that written file from application persistent data path to Firebase storage;
it works fine in Editor, but doesn't work in android APK.

I have found that android is an archive so it does not let system.io find the file.
so I am using www. and still cannot find a way. Help please.
Thank you very much in Advance :)

Comment: So what doesn't work: saving a csv at Android device or uploading to Firebase?

Comment: I Solved it, in apk my game can write to peristant datapath but cannot read the same written file with same file path ..i had to use different file path with same but add jar: and file:// at start to read it

Comment: It is possible that the JDK and SDK versions do not match. The selected Android version must match the version of JDK and SDK to be successfully generated!